# Sailsjs controlling the attributes returned by relationship property

Tags: sails.js

In my sailsjs app I have a data object that is returning a list of it's children objects. Now those children are returning complete attributes, is there a way for me to limit the children to return just one property (ex. the id)

currently i get something like this

```
{
    "name": "parent",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "id456",
            "name": "child",
            "createdAt": "2015-09-09T03:10:42.000Z",
            "dateAdded": "2014-10-10T04:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "id": "id123",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-09T03:10:42.000Z",
    "dateAdded": "2014-10-10T04:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I would like to get back this:

```
{
    "name": "parent",
    "children": [
        "id456"
    ],
    "id": "id123",
    "createdAt": "2015-09-09T03:10:42.000Z",
    "dateAdded": "2014-10-10T04:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Waterline [does have select](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md#select) which can be used in a criteria object, but I haven't seen this work as a criteria object for `.populate()`. There is [a bug](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1063#issuecomment-113534637) with `sails-mongo` that makes select work incorrectly. It looks like this will be [fixed shortly](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/compare/v0.11.2...master).

Anyways, if we assume that continues not to work, you could just map it:

```
Parent.find()
      .populate('children')
      .then(function(parent){
          parent.children = _.map(parent.children, function(c){return c.id}))
      })
```

It's kind of a pain but I have to do it often enough.

Comment: It seems like the function is not being called

I took your code
index: function (req, res) {
        Dataobjects.find()
            .populate('children')
            .then(function(parent){
                parent.children = _.map(parent.children, function(c){
                    console.log(c);
                    return c.id
                })
                return res.json(parent)
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err)
            })

    }

Comment: and also what are the performance setbacks on this approach, isn't it looping through all the objects from result and creating a new object